# Jquery carousel slider like recent app in mobile for web

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am struggling to find some jquery effect plugin for my responsive web app. I am looking for slider exact as in mobile recent app opens. I have search with different `coverflow`, `carousel slider` but not found any most of provide with horizontal slider and I want vertical. If you have any idea then please provide me some reference or guide me what should I do achieve the same as below image in my web app:
[image]

**Note:** It should mobile compatible for touch, swipe effect. I appreciate for your help.

Comment: Reference: [owl carousel slider](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo)

Comment: @JagdishParmar : thanks for your reference but this is not what I asked for. It's horizontal not vertical as image I post. Can I customized it accordingly?

Comment: Please reffer http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-3D-Flipping-Gallery-with-jQuery-CSS3/demo/ . it is not exactly as you want but you have to modify it to match it with your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found one jquery carousel what is I was looking for. Sorry to post as answer this is only for those who stuck in same issue like me in future so their time is not wasted to search.

### **[Theta carousel](http://theta-carousel.com/carousel-example.html#example=line1)**

[image]

It is paid but worth to pay as they are providing support also.